# How to move table from one tablespace to another in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, move

I run `oracle 11g` and need to move `table (tbl1)` from one `tablespace (tblspc1)` to another `(tblspc2)`. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Can you at least post what you have tried so far?.

Comment: If you want to move partitioned tables, I wrote some years ago how I moved tables from a tablespace to another: [move partitioned tables](http://floringhita.blogspot.ro/2011/05/oracle-move-partitoned-tables-to-anther.html).

Answer (score 72):

Try this:-

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE NAME to be moved> MOVE TABLESPACE <destination TABLESPACE NAME>
```

**Very nice suggestion from [IVAN](https://stackoverflow.com/users/836215/ivan) in comments so thought to add in my answer**

**Note**: this will invalidate all table's indexes. So this command is usually followed by

```
alter index <owner>."<index_name>" rebuild;
```

Comment: [From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables006.htm#i1106606); and [more here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_3001.htm#i2081902)

Comment: Note: this will invalidate all table's indexes. So this command is usually followed by "alter index <name> rebuild".

Comment: @Ivan:- Thanx Ivan. Nice point. Added this in the answer as well!! +1 :)

Comment: @RahulTripathi, I have more than 500+ tables how can I move them to another tablespace ?

Comment: @RahulTripathi, this is easy enough as you can spool and use SELECT to generate a SQL file from the table names, then execute the SQL file.  The problem I have is, when I execute the command I get ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.  I tried specifying schema.tablename with and without double-quotes as the source table, but no luck.

Comment: Building on the above, this will find obs tbs and generate  the ALTER in the same go...

  `SELECT Segment_Name,
       Segment_Type,
       Tablespace_Name,
       Bytes,
       Blocks,
       Extents,
       q'[ALTER ]' || Segment_Type || q'[ ]' || USER || q'[.]' ||
       Segment_Name || CASE
         WHEN Segment_Type = 'INDEX' THEN
          q'[ REBUILD ]'
         ELSE
          q'[ MOVE ]'
       END || q'[ TABLESPACE ]' || q'[TABLESPACE_NAME_GOES_HERE]' || q'[;]'
  FROM Dba_Segments
 WHERE Owner = USER
   AND Tablespace_Name <> 'TABLESPACE_NAME_GOES_HERE'
 ORDER BY Segment_Name;`

Comment: Nice idea Allen! Small correction: you have to put ' ... ' around ".... WHERE Owner = 'USER_GOES_HERE' AND ..." . Also you need to run the command as sysdba or else Dba_Segments table is not available.

Comment: Besides rebuilding the indexes you propably also want them to be moved to the same new tablespace. So the adjusted command would be:

alter index <owner>."<index_name>" rebuild tablespace <destination TABLESPACE NAME>

Comment: @Allen your comment should be a separate answer. However if there are LOB columns then they need to be excluded and moved separately using `ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME MOVE LOB(COLUMN_NAME) STORE AS (TABLESPACE DEST_TABLESPACE)`

Answer (score 11):

Use `sql` from `sql`:

spool output of this to a file:

```
select 'alter index '||owner||'.'||index_name||' rebuild tablespace TO_TABLESPACE_NAME;' from all_indexes where owner='OWNERNAME';
```

spoolfile will have something like this:

```
alter index OWNER.PK_INDEX rebuild tablespace CORRECT_TS_NAME;
```

Comment: You have to use " ... " around the index_name or else you will get an error "ORA-01418: specified index does not exist". So command should be: select 'alter index '||owner||'."'||index_name||'" rebuild tablespace TO_TABLESPACE_NAME;' from all_indexes where owner='OWNERNAME';

Comment: @Jan: that's only correct if the index name contain lower-case letters. If good practices are followed, by which I mean that all indexes are named using upper-case letters only, it is not necessary to quote the names.

Answer (score 11):

Moving tables:

First run:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE <schema_name>.' || OBJECT_NAME ||' MOVE TABLESPACE '||' <tablespace_name>; '
FROM ALL_OBJECTS
WHERE OWNER = '<schema_name>'
AND OBJECT_TYPE = 'TABLE' <> '<TABLESPACE_NAME>';
```

-- Or suggested in the comments (did not test it myself)

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE <SCHEMA>.' || TABLE_NAME ||' MOVE TABLESPACE '||' TABLESPACE_NAME>; ' 
FROM dba_tables 
WHERE OWNER = '<SCHEMA>' 
AND TABLESPACE_NAME <> '<TABLESPACE_NAME>
```

Where `<schema_name>` is the name of the user.
And `<tablespace_name>` is the destination tablespace.

As a result you get lines like:

ALTER TABLE SCOT.PARTS MOVE TABLESPACE USERS;

Paste the results in a script or in a oracle sql developer like application and run it.

Moving indexes:

First run:

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX <schema_name>.'||INDEX_NAME||' REBUILD TABLESPACE <tablespace_name>;' 
FROM ALL_INDEXES
WHERE OWNER = '<schema_name>'
AND TABLESPACE_NAME NOT LIKE '<tablespace_name>';
```

The last line in this code could save you a lot of time because it filters out the indexes which are already in the correct tablespace.

As a result you should get something like:

ALTER INDEX SCOT.PARTS_NO_PK REBUILD TABLESPACE USERS;

Paste the results in a script or in a oracle sql developer like application and run it.

Last but not least, moving LOBs:

First run:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE <schema_name>.'||LOWER(TABLE_NAME)||' MOVE LOB('||LOWER(COLUMN_NAME)||') STORE AS (TABLESPACE <table_space>);'
FROM DBA_TAB_COLS
WHERE OWNER = '<schema_name>' AND DATA_TYPE like '%LOB%';
```

This moves the LOB objects to the other tablespace.

As a result you should get something like:

ALTER TABLE SCOT.bin$6t926o3phqjgqkjabaetqg==$0 MOVE LOB(calendar) STORE AS (TABLESPACE USERS);

Paste the results in a script or in a oracle sql developer like application and run it.

O and there is one more thing:

For some reason I wasn't able to move 'DOMAIN' type indexes. As a work around I dropped the index. changed the default tablespace of the user into de desired tablespace. and then recreate the index again.
There is propably a better way but it worked for me.

Comment: SELECT 'ALTER TABLE <SCHEMA>.' || TABLE_NAME ||' MOVE TABLESPACE '||' <TABLESPACE_NAME> '
FROM dba_tables WHERE OWNER = '<SCHEMA>' AND TABLESPACE_NAME <> '<TABLESPACE_NAME>'; filter's tables already in desired tablespace

Comment: First query in the answer should be replaced with Barun`s query.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to move your table (tbl1) to tablespace (tblspc2).

```
alter table tb11 move tablespace tblspc2;
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried many scripts but they didn't work for all objects. You can't move clustered objects from one [tablespace](https://www.orahow.com/2018/06/move-all-objects-to-another-tablespace.html) to another. For that you will have to use expdp, so I will suggest expdp is the best option to move all objects to a different tablespace.

Below is the command:

```
nohup expdp \"/ as sysdba\" DIRECTORY=test_dir DUMPFILE=users.dmp LOGFILE=users.log TABLESPACES=USERS &
```

You can check [this link](https://www.orahow.com/2018/06/move-all-objects-to-another-tablespace.html) for details.

Comment: you should not use sysdba for exports if not Oracle Supports tell you to do it.

Comment: Export is not enough. You have to drop and  import the objects, too.